# how to fix this error JSON in java A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]

Tags: java, json, asp.net-web-api

I have managed to save the data in the BD, but when I get to JSONobject it goes to the exception and presents this error in METHOD POST:

```java
public int insertarCliente(Cliente c){
        //globalURL +=  "?rut=" + c.getRut() + "&nom="+ c.getNombre() +"&app=" + c.getApellidoP() + "&apm=" + c.getApellidoM();
        String globalURL = "http://localhost:60367/api/Cliente?rut=" + c.getRut() + "&nom="+ c.getNombre() +"&app=" + c.getApellidoP() + "&apm=" + c.getApellidoM();
        try {
            HttpURLConnection conn = Conectar(globalURL);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ACCEPT", "application/json");
            //conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "0");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.getOutputStream().close();
            if (conn.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String resp = br.readLine();
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(resp.trim());
                //JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(resp.trim());
                br.close();
                return obj.getInt("resp");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.getLogger(ClienteDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);

        }
        return 0;
    }
```

and presents the following error.

```
Grave:   org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:432)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:184)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:310)
```

Comment: What does the response string look like? The error is pretty self-explanatory, it sounds like the response is not formatted as proper JSON.

Comment: Will you please show us what is the value of the String `resp` by printing it in the console?

Comment: @AyyubKolsawala just print a number 1.

Comment: @MattU So should I do a for that runs the variable BR?

Comment: @AlexValenzuela no, inspect the contents of the `resp` variable and see if it's valid JSON.